# Creating Crosstabs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a survey asking about mobile device usage, but people have the option of checking more than one device...so folks may check iPad and Android phone, or folks can only check iPhone, etc.

I am trying to use Pivot Tables in Excel to have cross-tabs, but the rows are nested rather than stacked.

Nested:
[image]

Stacked (from SurveyMonkey):
[image]

I want them stacked rather than nested.
How can I accomplish this in Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I’m not at all sure that I understand your question, but does this

[image]

look something like what you want (or at least a step in the right direction)? 
Here are the formulae:

[image]

Here are columns F-H in a form that you can copy&paste:

```
       =$A$1                                =$B$1
=$A$1  =COUNTIFS(A2:A17,">0")               =COUNTIFS(A2:A17,">0",B2:B17,">0")
=$B$1  =COUNTIFS(A2:A17,">0",B2:B17,">0")   =COUNTIFS(B2:B17,">0")
=$C$1  =COUNTIFS(A2:A17,">0",C2:C17,">0")   =COUNTIFS(B2:B17,">0",C2:C17,">0")
```